# Simplest way to pass float[][] to C++ via JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

In my Java code I have a 2D float array `float[x][4] floatArray`. Here `x` can be between 1  and 25. I have to pass this 2D float array to a `C++` method via `JNI`. My `JNI` method is

```
jboolean MyJNIMethod(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jobjectArray myArray)
{
    //how to convert this myArray to something that can be safely passed to C++ method below
}
```

Inside `MyJNIMethod` I have to call a `C++` method and pass 2D float array taken from Java to this method

```
bool MyCplusPlusMethod(float coordinates[][4])
    {

    }
```

I am having a hard time in properly converting jobject to float[][] due to lack of native development knowledge. Can anyone tell me the simplest and safest possible way? Thanks

Comment: You could simplify this by converting (in Java) the 2D Java array to a Java row-major 1D array, and passing that into the float[][4]. In C++, the 1D and 2D arrays look the same in memory.

Comment: Second the suggestion for passing a one-dimensional array over the JNI. Remember that you'll also need to pass the size then.

Comment: I decided to use vector <vector <float > > inside JNI and C++. Now I am reading float[][] in JNI. Populating vector <vector <float> > and passing it to C++

Comment: Great - good choice. You still can use my example ;)

Answer (score 22):

Something like this should work:

```
jboolean MyJNIMethod(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jobjectArray myArray)
{
  int len1 = env -> GetArrayLength(myArray);
  jfloatArray dim=  (jfloatArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(myArray, 0);
  int len2 = env -> GetArrayLength(dim);
  float **localArray;
  // allocate localArray using len1
  localArray = new float*[len1];
  for(int i=0; i<len1; ++i){
     jfloatArray oneDim= (jfloatArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(myArray, i);
     jfloat *element=env->GetFloatArrayElements(oneDim, 0);
     //allocate localArray[i] using len2
     localArray[i] = new float[len2];
     for(int j=0; j<len2; ++j) {
        localArray[i][j]= element[j];
     }
  }
  //TODO play with localArray, don't forget to release memory ;)
}
```

Note that this is outline. It won't compile ;) (I wrote it in this overstacks' editor)

In your class you should declare native method:

```
 public native void myJNIMethod(float[][] m);
```

and in your c code corresponding:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_ClassName_methodName (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobjectArray);
```

Here is [JNI array operations documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#array_operations).

Comment: I think the problem is how would I pass a dynamic 2D float array created in JNI to a C++ method which takes a float[][]. I don't think that it is possible. Is it? If yes, what will be syntax?

Comment: Yes - it is possible. Look at my example localArray is the pointer to two-dimensional, native array. How you declare it is up to you. My example is showing how to fill it with data passed from Java.

Comment: I updated code with alocation of float[][] localArray (I didn't compile it).

Comment: I used this code but didn't know about 
`env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(oneDim, element, JNI_ABORT)` and `env->DeleteLocalRef(oneDim);`
So I got a memory leak until I figured that out, just a heads up

Answer (score 1):

For releasing the allocated memory you can do something like this:

```
static void releaseMatrixArray(JNIEnv *env, jobjectArray matrix) {
int size = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, matrix);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    jfloatArray oneDim = (jfloatArray) (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, matrix, i);
    jfloat *elements = (*env)->GetFloatArrayElements(env, oneDim, 0);

    (*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env, oneDim, elements, 0);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, oneDim);
  }
}
```

release local Array reference:

```
free(localArray);
```