# passing array of primitives from java to c

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a int array like

> int[][] coordinates = {{346, 640, 499, 666},{555, 640, 675, 666}};

and I am trying to send this array to C with using JNI. I could find clear solution for one dimensional array but not for multidimensional array.

```
public class PopulateCoordinates{
public native void Coordinates(int[][] coordinates);

 static {
  System.loadLibrary("libPopulateCoordinates");
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  PopulateCoordinates h = new PopulateCoordinates();
  int[][] coordinates = {{346, 640, 499, 666},{555, 640, 675, 666}};
  h.Coordinates(coordinates);
 }
 }
```

My JNI method is which will populate its array that is passed from java
like this

> rect skip_rectarr[2] = { {346, 640, 499, 666}, { 555, 640, 675, 666 }};

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL PopulateCoordinates_Coordinates(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,jobjectArray inJNIArray)
{
//rect skip_rectarr[2] = { {346, 640, 499, 666}, { 555, 640, 675, 666 }};
}
```

Can anyone please help me to tell how to do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6751825/417501

Comment: That example is for C++

Comment: The code should apply, too.